# Get a csv/txt list of users using the "net group" command

Tags: active-directory, net

I'm trying to end up with a txt file of usernames (1 user per line) using the

`net group /domain <group>`

command. However, the output of this command is not conducive to parsing. Does anyone have a way to pipe this to a txt file so that the file consists of only one user per line?

Comment: No Powershell? `Get-ADGroupMember "groupname" | Select name | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation output.csv`

Comment: @jscott, when I run that command in PS, I get: "The term Get-ADGroupMember is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...". Also I'd prefer to use a command that doesn't require additional installations if at all possible.

Comment: You need Microsoft's [Active Directory Powershell module](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx).  It's included in [RSAT](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887) and Server 2008/2012.

Comment: Might use [`dsget group`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731202.aspx) instead of `net /group`.  Powershell with the AD modules is the right way though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, no additional installs, I get it.  The following is horrible, horrible, and I would suggest there must be a better way [use the AD module!] to do it.  I didn't feel like writing this in batch just now, so here it is.  Note there isn't even a hint of i18n, error handling or anything "sane" here.

```
# Powershell
$result = net group /domain "SomeGroup"
($result |
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^(The request|$|Group Name|Comment|Members|--|The c)' }).Split(' ') |
        Where-Object { $_ } |
             Out-File group.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, and I think you're right... It'll be better to install the module.

Comment: You'll be so much happier with the AD module, I promise. :)